# Small graphs containing all trees on $n$ vertices

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

What do those graphs look like which contain a copy of every tree on $n$ vertices and such that no proper subgraph has this property?

Comment: Well, there is $K_n$